# Unix mail utility - 'You must specify direct recipients with -s, -c, or -b'

Tags: linux, email, unix

Wikipedia says that this should work:

```
echo "Some message" | mail -s "meeting today" somebody@example.com
```

But I do not get any mails, instead an error message:

```
$ echo "world" | mail -s "hello, " -c lazer@gmail.com
You must specify direct recipients with -s, -c, or -b.
$
```

What is the correct way to use `mail`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to send mail without specifying the `To:`, just who you are CC-ing it to.

Do something like:

```
echo "world" | mail -s "hello, " me@myself.com -c lazer@gmail.com
```

To send it to yourself, but CC it to the person you wanted to CC it to (or just send it to them without the `-c` flag)